# unique_ptr<T,Deleter> constructor requires that Deleter is nothrow

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, noexcept

[unique_ptr (constructor) @ cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr)

```
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d1 ) noexcept;
(3) 
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d2 ) noexcept;
(4)
```

Here are 2 constructors and the description for the case Deleter is non-reference

```
a) If D is non-reference type A, then the signatures are:
unique_ptr(pointer p, const A& d) noexcept;
(1) (requires that Deleter is nothrow-CopyConstructible)
unique_ptr(pointer p, A&& d) noexcept;
(2) (requires that Deleter is nothrow-MoveConstructible)
```

I checked both gcc and llvm code but I don't see `nothrow` requirement is enforced. Constructors 3-4 are marked `noexcept` so it makes sense that the `Deleter` should not throw when its constructors are called. But I'm not sure why in the example they provided the constructors are not marked as `noexcept`.

```
struct D { // deleter
    D() {};
    D(const D&) { std::cout << "D copy ctor\n"; }
    D(D&) { std::cout << "D non-const copy ctor\n";}
    D(D&&) { std::cout << "D move ctor \n"; }
    void operator()(Foo* p) const {
        std::cout << "D is deleting a Foo\n";
        delete p;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I checked both gcc and llvm code but I don't see `nothrow` requirement is enforced.

It's not enforced - directly.
Here's the [actual words from the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.ctor#12):

> For the first constructor, if `D` is not a reference type, `D` shall meet the `Cpp17CopyConstructible` requirements and such construction shall not exit via an exception. For the second constructor, if `D` is not a reference type, `D` shall meet the `Cpp17MoveConstructible` requirements and such construction shall not exit via an exception.

What that says is that if your copy/move constructor exits via an exception, you have undefined behavior. [ 'shall' in this case is a requirement on the user. ]

If you're lucky, then the program will call `terminate` with a nice message. However, you have no guarantees.

(Later) Note: The requirement is NOT that they be `noexcept`, but rather that they do not exit via an exception. That's why the examples on cppreference are fine.